# Will multiplexing impedance measurements from the AD5933 act as a series resisitance?

Tags: circuit-design, impedance, measurement

Image of block diagram of the AD5933 at: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Douglas_Dutra/publication/292976112/figure/fig1/AS:520210098917376@1501039160818/AD5933-Functional-Block-Diagram-10.png

I am going to attempt to multiplex the chips vout and vin so that the system can measure more than one impedance. Other than ON resistance will there be any other issues? as I can compensate for the series reisitance in software. I was intending on using a CD4051BEE4 multiplexer. Any  advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It will act as a nonlinear series resistance, plus there's some pF capacitance. From the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4053b.pdf)

[image]

[image]